# db error reinstalling CiviCRM

Tags: database

I'm just getting started with CiviCRM and trying to install on our WordPress site.

I completed the initial install once, but accidentally used the existing WordPress database - I would prefer to install on separate database.

So I have deleted the plugin, via WPadmin.  Removed CiviCRM tables from the database using the drop sql file.  Uploaded the CiviCRM files to server again and tried to activate the plugin.

The plugin is activated, but clicking the CiviCRM button in the lhs menu gives me error message below.  Seems like CiviCRM is looking to the old install in the WordPress database?

How to correct this please and reinstall in separate db?

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'huWP_db.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you planning to reinstall CiviCRM on separate database than you will need to delete the civicrm.settings.php file which holds all the db settings.

Since you are using wordpress you can locate the file in one of the place below

```
wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
```

or

```
wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: thank you Pradeep.  I have found the setting file in the uploads folder.  All good now:)

Comment: Cool. Can you mark this as Answered so that it will be useful for others?